# Making a light inside the box in processing

Tags: java, processing

I am a new coder in processing, so please be gentle. Normally, my code is more long and complex, but I prepared to you simple code which I can convert to my code.So, the code is:

```
void setup()
{
  size(1200, 800, P3D);
  camZ = (height/2) / tan((PI*60.0)/360.0);
  noStroke();
}
float camZ = 0;


void draw()
{
  background(0);

  camera(0, 0.0, camZ, //default camera position
  0, 0, -500, //where it is looking to
  0, 1, 0); //eye openness

  rotateX(rotX + distY);
  rotateY(rotY + distX);

  scale(100);
  drawHouse();

  if(keyPressed)
  {
    if(key == 'w')
      camZ -= 5;
    else if(key == 's')
      camZ += 5;
  }
}

void drawHouse()
{
  beginShape(QUADS);
  fill(255,0,0);
  //+Z face
  vertex(-1, -1, 1); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, 1); //upper right corner
  vertex(1, 1, 1); //bottom right corner
  vertex(-1, 1, 1); //bottom left corner

  fill(0,255,0);
  //-Z face
  vertex(-1, -1, -1); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -1); //upper right corner
  vertex(1, 1, -1); //bottom right corner
  vertex(-1, 1, -1); //bottom left corner

  fill(0,0,255);
  //+X face
  vertex(1, -1, 1); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -1);
  vertex(1, 1, -1);
  vertex(1, 1, 1);

  fill(255);
  //-X face
  vertex(-1, -1, 1); //upper left corner
  vertex(-1, -1, -1);
  vertex(-1, 1, -1);
  vertex(-1, 1, 1);

  fill(208,13,211);
  //-Y face
  vertex(-1, -1, 1);
  vertex(1, -1, 1);
  vertex(1, -1, -1);
  vertex(-1, -1, -1);

  fill(250,150,18);
  //+Y face
  vertex(-1, 1, 1);
  vertex(1, 1, 1);
  vertex(1, 1, -1);
  vertex(-1, 1, -1);
  endShape();
}

float rotX = 0, rotY = 0;
float lastX, lastY;
float distX, distY;

void mousePressed()
{
  lastX = mouseX;
  lastY = mouseY;
}

void mouseDragged()
{
  distX = radians(mouseX - lastX);
  distY = radians(lastY - mouseY);
}

void mouseReleased()
{
  rotX += distY;
  rotY += distX;
  distX = distY = 0;
}
```

So, I want to make a light inside the box which was given in the code. The light should effect only inside the box. How to make that happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! It made me curious and I had to investigate. I'm afraid that this is outside my confort zone, but I found something which may help you.

Your simplified code was great but I simplified it further to make things more obvious. First the code, then some explanations:

```
float camZ = 0;
float rotX = 0, rotY = 0;
float lastX, lastY;
float distX, distY;

void setup()
{
  size(1200, 800, P3D);
  camZ = (height/2) / tan((PI*60.0)/360.0);
  noStroke();
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  lights();  // We want to see what's outside the cube, too.

  camera(0, 0.0, camZ, //default camera position
    0, 0, -500, //where it is looking to
    0, 1, 0); //eye openness

  rotateX(rotX + distY);
  rotateY(rotY + distX);

  scale(100);
  pointLight(255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);  // this light is inside the cube. You cannot see it from outside (it's red, too)
  box(2);  //I made a white cube so the lightning will be more obvious

  if (keyPressed)
  {
    if (key == 'w')
      camZ -= 5;
    else if (key == 's')
      camZ += 5;
  }
}

void mousePressed()
{
  lastX = mouseX;
  lastY = mouseY;
}

void mouseDragged()
{
  distX = radians(mouseX - lastX);
  distY = radians(lastY - mouseY);
}

void mouseReleased()
{
  rotX += distY;
  rotY += distX;
  distX = distY = 0;
}
```

Have you tried to run it? From the outside, the box will be grey-white. If you move the camera inside the box, though, you'll see that the walls have red tints. Here's what's happening:

1. I used [lights()](https://processing.org/reference/lights_.html) to illuminate the sketch. It's basically a default [ambientLight](https://processing.org/reference/ambientLight_.html) in case you want to change it's values - it didn't matter for this demonstration. If you comment the line, you'll notice that you can't see anything outside the cube.
2. I added a [pointLight](https://processing.org/reference/pointLight_.html) in the middle of the cube. A pointlight will act like a small lightbulb: it's omnidirectional.

My pointlight is red, si it will light only red surfaces (in this case, the white walls looks red because white has a red part in RGB).

I hope this will get you started on the right path. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much @Iaancelot it helps me a lot. I learnt to logic. Thank you so much.